# user referral algorithm / equation for user totals at a specific time

Tags: algorithm, equation

I am trying to formulate an equation to determine the number of users at a given time based on an input of new users every XX amount of time and their referred users.

Basically, We expect to be manually adding 100 users to the system every week. We are assuming that every new user refers one more user every following week. Each of those new users will refer one user the following week and so on. We would like a simple equation that we can input the week # and then return the number of total users at the end of that week. I have accomplished this using a for-loop but would like to have it in one simple equation if possible.

Here is some example data and expected results (totals) for the first few weeks.

```
Week 1        Week 2        Week 3        Week 4        Week 5
100 added     100 referred  100 referred  100 referred  100 referred
              100 added     100 referred  100 referred  100 referred
                            100 added     100 referred  100 referred
                                          100 added     100 referred
                                                        100 added

100 total     300 total     600 total     1000 total    1500 total
```

Also, what if the share rate is only 1 new user for every 2 users (50% share rate)?

```
Week 1        Week 2        Week 3        Week 4        Week 5
100 added     50 referred   25 referred   12.5 referred 6.25 referred
              100 added     50 referred   25 referred   12.5 referred
                            100 added     50 referred   25 referred
                                          100 added     50 referred
                                                        100 added

100 total     250 total     425 total     612.5 total   806.25 total
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]

I have found this equation to work for a 1:1 share ratio based on simply noticing the pattern in the above table but I am not sure how to implement the share rate into the equation, how does the 50 actually come into play?

```
$rate = 1;
$increase = 100;
$week = 5;

$balance = ($increase*$week) + (50 * ($week-1) * $week);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: In which language do you do this equation?

Comment: currently I am testing the equation with PHP I have added an edit which solves the 1:1 ratio but I do not understand part of it enough to adapt it to different share ratios.

Comment: Week three should be 425 by your table (250 + 100 + 50 + 25). the rest of the table needs to be updated too.

Comment: Thanks mike, durp moment there - edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You originally didn't specify a language so I wrote a solution in ruby:

```
sum_of_exponential_decays = -> n { (0..n).map {|n| 100 * 0.5**n}.reduce(:+)}
sum_of_n = -> n {(1..n).inject(0) { |acc,x| acc += sum_of_exponential_decays[x-1]}}
sum_of_n[5]
# => 806.25
```

The code seems pretty clear and it's summing exponential decays as it says.

For additional explanation look at the sum_of_exponential decays function, the reduce(:+) simply sums all the elements in it and:

```
exponential_decays = -> n { (0..n).map {|n| 100 * 0.5**n}}
(1..5).map {|x| exponential_decays[x] }
# => [[100.0, 50.0],
 [100.0, 50.0, 25.0],
 [100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5],
 [100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25],
 [100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125]]
```

Comment: This solution does work however what I am looking for is more of a one line mathematical equation to solve this. I have been able to solve using a simple loop. Sorry I cannot yet vote-up the answer due to my reputation.

Comment: If that's what you want read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay). The solution is that of a differential equation, you are adding 100 units to the system each time step and each time step is equivalent to a half life of your units. However, you're trying to solve a differential equation so you might as well use integration which is analagous to a for loop in this equation.

Comment: In fact I'll go even further, the equation you need to solve is dN/dt = -0.5 * N + 100. EDIT: scratch that, because time is discretized in your case (you are adding the 100 only at the timesteps) this continuous equation will not work.

Comment: Hmm yes, I was doing some unsuccessful tests with that equation, I guess the real hurdle here is that additional 100 added at every interval? Is the equation in my edit above just luck and way off course?

Comment: umm, the equation I added was a differential equation that needed to be solved to give a usable equation, if you just wanted an equation for the top case it's simply the sum of integers so n*(n+1)/2 (* 100)